# VeeValidate, Confirmed rule not working on ValidationProvider

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I am trying to add vee-validate rule on Validation Provider of password and confirm password. v-validate must be working where I had to add rules to a textbox. But here in my case, I must have to use Validation Provider. Please help!!!

**Versions**

```
vee-validate: 2.1.7
vue: 2.9.6
```

**Code**

```
<ValidationObserver ref="adminInfo">
<v-layout row wrap>
<v-flex xs12 md6>
    <ValidationProvider name="password" rules="required|min:5|max:35" ref="password">
    <v-text-field
      solo
      v-model="administratorInfo.newPassword"
      label="Set New Password"
      required

      slot-scope="{
          errors,
          valid
        }"
      :error-messages="errors"
      :success="valid"
    ></v-text-field>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs12 md6>
    <ValidationProvider name="confirm password" rules="'required|confirmed:password'">
    <v-text-field
      solo
      v-model="administratorInfo.cNewPassword"
      label="Confirm Password"
      required
      slot-scope="{
          errors,
          valid
        }"
      :error-messages="errors"
      :success="valid"
    ></v-text-field>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
</ValidationObserver>
```

Getting error:

**Cannot read property '$watch' of undefined**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found solution by replacing ref="password" to vid="password". Found solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yw8yrmn9y9).

But I did not understood what is and why vid?

Comment: When using `validation-provider` you must use `vid` instead of `ref`:

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/components/validation-provider.html#cross-field-validation

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for how to pass `vid` when `rules` are an object:

```
<validation-provider :rules="{ required: true, max: 100, confirmed: 'confirmar' }" v-slot="validationContext"> </validation-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be unrelated but make sure you have a `v-model` in your `ValidationProvider` of confirm password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).